# What to do of a reward card after it is empty?

Tags: debit-card

Recently I enrolled in a no cost trial offer with a company. For that they sent me a $10 reward card. I used it up for buying groceries. Is the reward card useful anymore? Or should I just cut it up and throw it away?

Comment: Keep the card; it can be used to open locked doors (not ones with deadbolts, though)

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate : Yeah that's sound's good. I guess I will rub it with a magnet and do just that.


          @ To the person who down-voted: please tell me my error so that the next time I won't repeat it on this forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should cut it up and discard it, as it is useless. Future reward cards don't need old cards to add balances to. The physical card has no cost to the giver, and once empty, is of no value to you.